# COMPILATION ERROR error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: smart-contract, compilation, eosio-cpp

what is causing this error while im compiling ?

````
struct [[eosio::table]] requestForLoan{
      uint64_t req_id;
      name borr_name;
      uint64_t borr_id;
      name uwr_name;
      uint64_t uwr_id;
      double loan_amount;
      double interest_rate;
      uint64_t loan_duration;
      bool approvalStatus=false;
      uint64_t primary_key() const {
      return req_id;
      }
      auto get_borrower() const{
      return borr_name.value;
      }
    };

typedef eosio::multi_index <"requestLoan"_n,requestForLoan>requestLoan;
requestLoan reqLoan_table;```


 **error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    typedef eosio::multi_index <"requestLoan"_n,requestForLoan_info> requestLoan;**
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"requestLoan"** isn't a valid name for an EOSIO table; it only supports lower-case names using alpha characters.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/naming-conventions#section-table-names-structs-functions-classes